# Confusing behavior: Connection.query return empty. Unless another connection is got from the pool and released immediately

Tags: javascript, mysql

below Ive pasted a function that validates and approves a paypal order. Ive been trying to fix an issue for a while now, where the first query just return an empty [] for no apparent reason. I think it might be an issue with race conditions, but I dont know.
The interesting thing is that the query DOES work when I quickly get a connection from the pool and instantly release it.
I´d love an explanation to why this might be happening...
TL;DR:
Query only work when getting and releasing a connection right before it.

```js
async function validateAndApproveOrder(paypal_id, status, accessToken) {
    const sql = "SELECT total_price FROM Orders WHERE paypal_id = ?"
    const sqlTwo = "UPDATE Orders SET order_status = 'Processing' WHERE paypal_id = ?"
    const url = `${baseURL.sandbox}/v2/checkout/orders/${paypal_id}`;
  
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      }
    })
    const data = await response.json();
    const payment = data.purchase_units[0].amount.value;
    
    connection.getConnection((err, connect) => {
      connect.release();
    })
    if(data.status === "COMPLETED" && data.intent === "CAPTURE" && status === data.status) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connection.getConnection((err, connection) => {
          if(err) {
            connection.release();
            reject("connection error while validating: " + err);
          }
          console.log("pid: ", paypal_id);
          connection.query(sql, [paypal_id], (err, results) => {
            if(err) {
              connection.release();
              reject("query error while validating: " + err);
            }
            console.log("results: " + JSON.stringify(results));
            let price;
            if(results.length > 0) {
              const unconverted = results[0].total_price;
              price = unconverted.toFixed(2);
            }

            if(payment === price) {
             connection.query(sqlTwo, [paypal_id], (err) => {
              if(err) {
                connection.release();
                reject("query error while validating: " + err);
              }
              connection.release();
              resolve("OK");
             }) 
            }
          })
        })
      })
    } else {
    console.error("Verification Error: " + data.status + " -- " + status + " -- " + data.intent)
      return;
    }
}
```